# Best practices for mapStateToProps value assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am right now working on a project in which there are quite some teams involved, and there is a little mess around where the variables are initialized and communicated to the store.

It seems like the store is mainly looking like the following.

```
const initialState = {
    myStoreData: null
}

export default (state) => {
    ...
    return state
}
```

Then later in the component the team is writing things like the following. In which they reference the variable that was poorly initialized in the store, and they are setting there the value for the prop.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
  return {
    someValue: state.myStoreData.someValue || '',
    someOtherProperty: state.myStoreData.someOtherProperty || '',
    anotherProperty: state.anotherProperty || false, // NOTE: This one doesn't exist in the store for example
  };
```

Is there some kind of baked article that shows best practices regarding where would be the best place to keep the initial state of the application, and whether doing this kind of assignments are calling for bugs, or just simple ways to not have to modify the store `initialState` each time?

For me it seems like calling fro trouble, but still, I couldn't find the article backing me up

Answer (score 1):

It's good to have the initialState on the reducer, so you know exactly what properties and initial values are to put in your state.

For an advanced usage of using mapStateToProps, you can check this article, [React, Reselect and Redux](https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-reselect-and-redux-b34017f8194c). It uses [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect) which is very performant, efficient and composable. It is very suitable for large applications with a lot of state in redux.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree with the correlation between the initial state of your store and the default value of what a UI expects, to me they are two separate problems.

For example, `myStoreData.someValue` could be represented as `null` in the store because it's never been set, but when rendering the UI `null` maybe doesn't make sense e.g. if you are binding that field to an `input`, therefore you want to swap `null` for `''` or even a preset `'YES'` / `'NO'` etc. but just for the purpose of rendering - I personally don't see why this should be dictated by your data model.

In `mapStateToProps` you are effectively creating a [view model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel), so it's the point where you prepare data for the view, so I don't see anything wrong with the code in your question (apart from the lack of [selector](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) use, but that's a different topic). If you simply don't like the idea of it being done at that point then you could move the logic completely into the view which keeps it self-contained, view specific, and makes it a clear intention that the incoming data should come straight from the store and any fix-ups happen at view level e.g.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // let the view set the expected default values for the missing props
  defaultProps: {
    someProperty: '',
    someOtherProperty: '',
    anotherProperty: false
  }
}
...
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
  // build a view model based on the properties that you expect, 
  // don't include props that don't have a value or not set
  const vm = {};
  const { myStoreData } = state;
  if (typeof myStoreData.someValue === 'string') {
    vm.someValue = myStoreData.someValue;
  }
  if (typeof myStore.someOtherProperty === 'string') {
    vm.someOtherProperty = myStoreData.someOtherProperty;
  }
  if (typeof myStore.anotherProperty === 'boolean') {
    vm.anotherProperty = myStore.anotherProperty;
  }
  return vm;
}
```

You could leverage a validation lib like [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) for simplicity, but you get the idea.